# How to link/communicate data changes in dbf files to postgresql?

Tags: postgresql-9.1, dbf

I have a weighbridge software in dbf file that needs to linked to new software in postgresql, how I linked the detail/summary data to read day to day updated data ?

Can I directly linked it without any manual intervention like export and import using csv files, etc ?